# How to make my MySQL databases available at all times? Some expert DB advice needed!

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, replication

I've been doing a lot of research, reading on replication, etc but just not sure as to what mysql solution would work.

This is what I'm looking at:

- when my mysql fails for some reason or there are certain queries that are taking really long to execute and locking some tables, I want the other insert/update/select queries to still function at normal speed without having to wait for locks to be released or for the main database to be back up. I'm thinking there should be a second mysql server for this to happen, but is what I mentioned possible even if there is and would it involve a lot of change in my existing programming logic?
- when my database is being backed up, I would still like my site to function normally, all inserts/selects/updates should function as normal.
- when I need to alter a large table, I wouldn't like it to affect my application, there should be a backup server to work from.

So what do I need to do to get all this done and also would it require changing plenty of existing coding to suit the new set up? [My site has a lot of reads and writes]

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy way.  You're asking for a highly-available MySQL-based setup, and that requires a lot of work at the server and client ends.

Some issues, for example:

> - when I need to alter a large table, I wouldn't like it to affect my application, there should be a backup server to work from.

If you're altering the table, you can't trivially create a copy to work from during the update.  What about the changes that are made to your copy while the first update is taking place?

Have a search for "High Availability MySQL".  It's mostly a solved problem, but the solution depends heavily on your exact requirements.  You cannot just ask for "I want my SQL server to run at full speed always forever no matter what I throw at it".

Comment: I was only if there's such a set up possible where when you run an alter on the database, the server can use perhaps another backup live database for the time being and when the alter is done on the 1st database, the data can move from the 2nd database to the 1st one (assuming it's just an added field and not a rename) and then the alter can run on the 2nd db. Although thinking about it, doesn't sound realistic. But anyway have researched on high availability, it all just seems so complex and confusing. Will try to figure though!

Comment: Good luck!  HA is a tricky beast to get right without spending too much. Try to determine your actual exposed risk first, which should give you a cost/effort limit.  With a 1 hour downtime will you loose £1, £100 or £1m?

Answer (score 0):

Not a MySQL specific answer, but a general one. Have a read only copy of your DB for site to render, which will be synced to the master DB regularly. This way, you can keep your site working even if the master DB is under load/lock due to insert/delete. For efficiency, keep this copy as denormalized as you can.

Comment: If there's a read only copy then how will my other insert/update statements work, I want my site to function as normal even if there's a load on the main db. Or did you mean something else by a "read only copy of DB".

Comment: Read only copy = DB to render pages.
Master DB = Your actual DB, current DB, all your site CMS, insert delete should work on this.
And you should somehow sync your Read only copy to master one to keep site updated.